# JWplayer fullscreen not working on Ionic/cordova application

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, jwplayer

I am using JWplayer on Ionic application to build an android application.

```
      var player = jwplayer('playerMDnYyJnMcAHv');
      player.setup({
            file:  $stateParams.playlistUrl,
            image: $stateParams.poster,
            width: '100%',
            aspectratio: '16:9',
            androidhls: 'true',
            stretching: "fill",
            skin: "bekle",
            advertising: {
                client: 'vast',
                tag   : $stateParams.vast,
            },
            cast:{
                      appid:"724D0CE5",
              },
              tracks: [{ 
                  "file": "js/b.vtt", 
                  "label": "English",
                  "kind": "captions",
                  "default": true 
                      }]
        });
       $scope.play = function()
               {
                // alert('jjj');
                jwplayer('playerMDnYyJnMcAHv').play();
                };
```

This is how i configured Jwplayer on  my application.

[image: Player screenshot]
​This is how my player looks like on application.

The problem is when i am changing player into full screen on **portrait** mode.This is how player looks like when player is fullscreen on portrait mode.
[image: Fullscreen screenshot]
​
But actually this is not the right way to show fullscreen on portrait mode.Could anyone help to show correct fullscreen mode like this

[image: fullscreen correct screenshot]
​

Comment: You might want to look into our official SDK for Android. We really do not have official support for the player inside of an app like this as it has not been tested in this way.

Comment: does this work with ios ?